# Difference in android layout designs between versions 2.3.3 and 4+

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I'm facing a strange issue in my project when creating a simple xml design as follow:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button" 
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
```

Now see the difference, this is the view in **4.2.2** :

[image: 2.3.3 version]

And this one in **2.3.3**:

[image]

Would appreciate if someone can help me with it. thanks

Comment: out of curiosity why are you trying to set layout_gravity to both left and center_vertical?

Comment: Uhm... So what's the difference? Do you want it to be "holofied"?

Comment: @Ahmad the black bar (the margin presumably) is on opposite sides

Comment: @UdiOshi also where is the dotted line in your images coming from? Are you posting the entire layout file here? I don't see anything that should create that line.

Comment: That's not dotted lines its just pressed with my mouse :)

Comment: Is this the preview from eclipse? Run your code on a device. The layout previewer is not perfect, you might be finding something that affects the previewer but not real devices / emulators.

Comment: It's the same on the device. and i'm using intelliJ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works, if you change it to this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="New Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*(I think I know why it behaves like this, let me just check something. I'll add an explanation later on)*

Comment: Hi Ahmad, this only solved the layout here which made to ask the real answer. in my project i have very complex layout which cannot be changed in this way. waiting for your explanation. thanks

Comment: @UdiOshi Sorry, my assumption was wrong (Or at least I can't find any evidence to support it). But however, setting `layout_gravity` to the top level layout with whatever gravity fixes it.

Comment: thanks Ahmad, but in my  other complexes layouts if i'll set layout gravity it will destroy everything :(

Comment: You have to set `layout_gravity` to the top level layout. This will apply gravity to your window inside the `DecorView`. (I think)

Comment: The main issue is it's not playing with my already defined layout and trying to fix it by gravity. We need to find the main reason of why this is happening to learn for the next time :) , I really thought that it's common issue between versions.... :)

Comment: Haha that's not a common problem at all. We have been discussing that in the Android chat room, but haven't found the definite cause of it yet. They are suggesting, that you wrap your whole layout in an other layout. A FrameLayout, LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. This should definitely solve it :)

Comment: Well....that's not a solution for anything :) but it's google...they can surprise you anymore...thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, in my case I had something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/match"
    android:background="@color/light"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/lateral_margin" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/full_screen_image"
        style="@style/match_width"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_content_description"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/barcode_number"
        style="@style/match_width"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_text"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem was solved changing

```
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/lateral_margin" >
```

with:

```
    android:padding="@dimen/lateral_margin" >
```

It seems androids 2.3.3 and lower were computing the margin differently than android 4 and greater. Now all of them behave the same way.

In your case, maybe setting the black layouts margin as padding could help.